# System.NullReferenceException when trying to iterate list in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Im a bit new at mvc, and i dont find out what am i miss. When i launch the login, in the view at foreach (var item in Model) <- the Model gets null, and stops with a System.NullReferenceException. A dont really have a clue why, and i hope somebody can give some advice what's wrong with the following code or where to start looking for the error.

The model:

```
    public class LoginModels
    {
       public string UserLogin { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
       public List<string> emailSubject { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string address, string password, LoginModels model)
    {
        using (Imap imap = new Imap())
        {
            try
            {
                imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com");
                imap.Login(address, password);
                imap.SelectInbox();
                List<long> uids = imap.Search(Flag.All);

                model.emailSubject = new List<string>();                   
                foreach (long uid in uids)
                {
                    var eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
                    IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(eml);

                    model.emailSubject.Add(email.Subject);
                }

                Session["user"] = new LoginModels() { UserLogin = address, Address = address };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", model.emailSubject);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewBag.exceptionMessage = e;
                return View("LoginFailed");
            }
        }
```

The view:

```
    @using TheOnlineArchivator.Models;
    @model List<TheOnlineArchivator.Models.LoginModels>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
     }
    @{
        var user = Session["user"] as LoginModels;
        if (user != null)
        {
           <h2>You are logged on as @user.Address</h2>
           <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               foreach (var elem in item.emailSubject)
               {
                  <tr>
                     <td>@elem</td>
                  </tr>
               }
            }
            </table>
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to pass an instance of `List<TheOnlineArchivator.Models.LoginModels>` to the view when you rendered this view inside your controller action. What you have shown so far is your Login controller action but you didn't show us your Home/Index action. Inside this action you should make sure that you are passing a non-null model to the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<LoginModels> model = ... go get your model from somewhere and make sure it is not null
        return View(model);
    }
}
```